# Android targetSDKVersion 19 but where is support library

Tags: android

I have

```
targetSDKVersion 19
```

and trying to use

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:19.0.+'
```

is giving me an error `failed to resolve ...`

When I go to SDK Manager, I can only see Android Support Library rev 23.1.1 available for download.

If I use that version 23, then I have the error `this support library should not use a different version ...`

My searches only bring up the fact I need to install same version of support library as I have targetted SDK - however as above, I can't find it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target SDK version and the version of the library must match. So rather than using the support library in version 19, upgrade your targetSDKVersion to 23 and also use the support library in version 23.1.1.
If that doesn't work out of the box, try installing the google support repository from the SDK Manager.

Comment: This doesn't make sense because surely there is a way to still target version 19 ? Isn't that the purpose of the support library ?

Comment: You only build against version 23, that does not mean you can't run the app on a version below 23. You can define a minSdkVersion for setting the minimum android version your app supports. TargetSDKVersion should always be updated to the latest available version if possible.

Comment: oh right, now i get it , that confused me! Will try that , thx

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
```

and change your gradle file

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: Yeh above, I tried that and it says `This support library should not use a different version (23) than the compiledSDKVersion (19)